# inequality of Supremum of Derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that
$f \in C^2 (\mathbb R)$ and $M_k=sup_x |f^{(k)}(x)|$ for $k=0,1,2$

Then $M_1^2 \leq 2M_0 M_2$


I guess : 


By Taylor's theorem, for $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ and $h\gt0$, $\exists a \in (x,x+h)$ such that
$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+f''(a)\frac{h^2}{2}$ 
$\Rightarrow |f'(x)|=\left| (f(x+h)-f(x)) \frac{1}{h}-f''(a) \frac{h}{2} \right|$
$\leq(|f(x+h)|+|f(x)|) \frac{1}{h}+|f''(a)| \frac{h}{2}$
$\leq \frac{2}{h}M_0 + \frac{h}{2}M_2$
Taking the infimum on right term, by AM–GM inequality, $M_1 \leq 2\sqrt{M_0M_2}$
Thus $M_1^2 \leq 4M_0M_2$

The coefficient is little different from that I want.
How can I modify?

Comment: Write $f(x-h)=f(x)-hf^{\prime}(x)+f^{\prime\prime}(b)\frac{h^2}{2}$ and compute $f(x+h)-f(x-h)$.